# Swift - Display glitch on iOS 13 on presentViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, ios13, presentviewcontroller

I recently upgraded all my iOS devices to iOS 13.3 and I noticed something that looks like a display glitch.

Every time I move from one VC to another using presentViewController, I am able to see the VC stack, for some reason.

Here is the code I am using:

```
let productsViewController = ProductsVC(productsArray: self.productsArray)
self.present(productsViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

As you can see, on iOS 12 or older, there is no problem. 
And unfortunately this happens on all of my apps.
Also, there is no error / warning and I am not sure what to look at / for.

Any ideas?

[image: Display Glitch On iOS 13]

Comment: This is the new default modal presentation in iOS 13.  If you want fullscreen presentation you have to specifically set the `modalPresentationStyle` to `.fullscreen`

Comment: @Paulw11 - Thanks. Seems to be working.

Comment: @KeshuR. - Thanks. Not sure how I missed that but it works.

Comment: Before presenting the view controller, add line `productsViewController. modalPresentationStyle = .fullscreen`